# How can I animate numbers in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

How can I animate number starting from 0 to the number's value like the following example :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a Flutter package that helps to do this. You can add it to your `pubspec.yaml` by using the following command in your terminal :

```
flutter pub add countup
```

and now add this line to your dart code :

```
import 'package:countup/countup.dart';
```

and finally add the widget by writing this code :

```
     Countup(
              begin: 0,
              end: 268000, //here you insert the number or its variable
              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
              separator: ',', //this is the character you want to add to seperate between every 3 digits
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 36,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase it with delay and update the screen in app

```
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
  setState(() {
    i++;
  });
});
```

Comment: updating is not animating